# Computing the dimension of a vector space in terms of matrix rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $V=\mathbb C^n$ be a complex vector space, and $A,B:V\to V$ two commuting endomorphisms. I am interested in determining the dimension of the vector space $$F_{AB}=\{(a,b)\in  V\times V\,|\,A\cdot b=B\cdot a\}.$$

Since they commute, up to a change of basis we can restrict to both $A,B$ upper triangular (if that helps).

> Is it the case that if we fix
>   $r_A=\textrm{rk}\,(A),\,r_B=\textrm{rk}\,(B)$ then $\dim F_{AB}$
>   depends only on $n,r_A,r_B$?

Attempt: The system $A\cdot b=0$ has $n-r_A$ independent solutions, and for every $v\in \textrm{image }(B)$ the solution set of $A\cdot b=v$ is a translate of that vector space of dimension $n-r_A$. I am tempted to say that there is a $\mathbb C^{n-r_A}$ for every such $v$, and since $v$ ranges in $\mathbb C^{r_B}$ the answer should be: $\dim F_{AB}=n-r_A+r_B$. But this conflicts with the obvious fact that $\dim F_{AB}=n$ when $A$ or $B$ is invertible. Any insight is very welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it also depends on if the ranges of $A$ and $B$ overlap.

Let
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
~~~~
B = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so $AB = BA = 0$. We have the nullspaces of $A$ and $B$:
$$\begin{align}
N(A) &= \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ t_1 \end{pmatrix} : t_1 \in \mathbb C \right\} \\
N(B) &= \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} t_2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} : t_2 \in \mathbb C \right\}
\end{align}$$
so a sufficient condition for $Ab = Ba$ is if $b \in N(A), a \in N(B)$, which gives a two-dimensional subspace in $F_{AB}$ on the form $\{(a,b): a \in N(B), b \in N(A)\}$.

If one of $a$ or $b$ are in the nullspace of $B$ or $A$, respectively, but not the other, we can obviously not have $Ab = Ba$.

Assume now that $b \notin N(A), a \notin N(B)$. The ranges of $A$ and $B$ are:
$$\begin{align}
R(A) = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} s_1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} : s_1 \in \mathbb C \right\} \\
R(B) = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ s_2 \end{pmatrix} : s_2 \in \mathbb C \right\} \\
\end{align}$$
and the intersection of these spaces is $\{0\}$, so if $a$ and $b$ are not in the respective nullspaces, we will never have a solution to $Ab = Ba$. Thus the whole space $F_{AB} = \{(a,b): a \in N(B), b \in N(A)\}$, so $\dim F_{AB} = 2$.

Now consider the case
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
~~~~
B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
i.e. $B = A$ and note that the ranks of these matrices are the same as the ranks in the previous example.

We will still have a subspace $\{(a,b): a \in N(B), b \in N(A)\}$ in $F_{AB}$, but we will also have the subspace $\{(c,c): c \notin N(A)\}$, so in this case $\dim F_{AB} \geq 3$.

But from the above example you can see that you always have 
$$\dim F_{AB} \geq \dim N(A) + \dim N(B) = 2n - r_A - r_B.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! So can we say that $\dim F_{AB}=2n-r_A-r_B+\dim\, (\textrm{im }A\cap \textrm{im }B )$ ?

Comment: I am not sure, but it sounds reasonable.